# django serializer with nested column

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm calling the following serializer -

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Resmst
        resource_name = 'resmst'
        fields = ('resmst_id', 'resmst_name', 'resmst_desc', 'resmst_limit', 'resmst_inuse', 'resmst_active', 'resmst_lstchgtm', 
            'resmst_prntid', 'resmst_owner', 'resmst_public', 'resmst_locked', 'resmst_offline')
        read_only_fields = ('resmst_id',)
```

resmst_owner is a FK relation to another table.  What I want to do is have the serializer display the information from a column where that FK relates.

This is the current json -

```
[
    {
        "resmst_id": 204, 
        "resmst_name": "GAWK", 
        "resmst_desc": null, 
        "resmst_limit": 1, 
        "resmst_inuse": 0, 
        "resmst_active": "Y", 
        "resmst_lstchgtm": "2014-08-20T11:15:18", 
        "resmst_prntid": null, 
        "resmst_owner": 822, 
        "resmst_public": "Y", 
        "resmst_locked": null, 
        "resmst_offline": 0
    }
]
```

And this is how I want it to look -

```
[
    {
        "resmst_id": 204, 
        "resmst_name": "GAWK", 
        "resmst_desc": null, 
        "resmst_limit": 1, 
        "resmst_inuse": 0, 
        "resmst_active": "Y", 
        "resmst_lstchgtm": "2014-08-20T11:15:18", 
        "resmst_prntid": null, 
        "owner_name": "John Smith", 
        "resmst_public": "Y", 
        "resmst_locked": null, 
        "resmst_offline": 0
    }
]
```

Or am I stuck with having to do it this way -

```
[
    {
        "resmst_id": 204, 
        "resmst_name": "GAWK", 
        "resmst_desc": null, 
        "resmst_limit": 1, 
        "resmst_inuse": 0, 
        "resmst_active": "Y", 
        "resmst_lstchgtm": "2014-08-20T11:15:18", 
        "resmst_prntid": null, 
        "resmst_owner": {
            "owner_name": "John Smith"
        }, 
        "resmst_public": "Y", 
        "resmst_locked": null, 
        "resmst_offline": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this but it looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25686950/2686688). Try to use a `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction with the help of @Steven I got it working.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be fine with a regular [Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#field) (note that this is readonly).

```
class ResourceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner_name = serializers.Field(source='resmst_owner.owner_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Resmst
        resource_name = 'resmst'
        fields = ('resmst_id', 'resmst_name', 'resmst_desc', 'resmst_limit', 
            'resmst_inuse', 'resmst_active', 'resmst_lstchgtm', 
            'resmst_prntid', 'resmst_owner', 'resmst_public', 
            'resmst_locked', 'resmst_offline', 'owner_name', )
        read_only_fields = ('resmst_id',)
```

Don't forget to add it to Meta.fields (as above).

See the section on [Core arguments](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#core-arguments):

> source
>
> The name of the attribute that will be used to populate the
> field. May be a method that only takes a self argument, such as
> Field(source='get_absolute_url'), or may use dotted notation to
> traverse attributes, such as Field(source='user.email').
>
> The value source='*' has a special meaning, and is used to indicate
> that the entire object should be passed through to the field. This can
> be useful for creating nested representations. (See the implementation
> of the PaginationSerializer class for an example.)
>
> Defaults to the name of the field.

Comment: Thanks the first one got me the solution but this one gave me the more elegant "what I was looking for".